# Transformer Core selection for flyback converter for 20 watts output power with detailed explanation

Tags: transformer, core

Formula for transformer core design for given specifications for flyback converter.

Comment: This isn't a "gimme the formulaz" site. Try to find something yourself and show it here then maybe someone will say if that is correct or not. Your question is to broad and vague. It also smells like homework, which is OK, but then you need to show what you have found.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly simple. You need 20 watts output power and therefore, per switching cycle you need to transfer 20 (watts) / frequency (Hz) in joules. Then decide what peak current you need in the primary to convey that energy to the secondary (taking into account an efficiency of around 85%). Then work out how much inductance you need based on the minimum supply voltage into your flyback converter.

Swish these numbers around a few times to optimize inductance and peak current and double check the numbers. Then, armed with a few core data sheets work out how many primary turns you need.

Peak current x number of primary turns divided by the effective core length gives you the peak H field. Then look up the permeability of your core and see what the peak flux density will be for that H field. If it's less than around 250 mT then you are probably good to go. If it's more than this you may decide to apply a gap to the core then, it's back to figuring out how many turns you might need to obtain the original inductance.

Comment: Very big grin .